# What's the best way to manage claims with WIF 4.5

Tags: authorization, wif, claims-based-identity, claims, wif4.5

I've recently been digging into WIF 4.5 in order to retrofit an older role based Webforms application with finer grained permissions.  The application is using Windows Auth, so it appears to be relatively straightforward to implement claims based authorization.  I can decorate pages and methods with ClaimsPrincipalPermission identifying the resource and action.  And I can plug-in a custom AuthorizationManager to apply the authorization rules.  There are plenty of good examples of how to do this. Here are a few:

- [Leveraging claims based security in asp.net 4.5](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/leveraging-claims-based-security-in-aspnet-45.aspx)
- [Going beyond usernames and roles](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/09/01/going-beyond-usernames-and-roles.aspx)
- [Identity and Access Control in WCF 4.5](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/iac-wcf/table-of-contents)

What I can't seem to find are good examples of how to best manage the users' claims. There are two basic challenges that I see.

- How do I keep the application claims in sync with the user claims? 
  How do I discover or keep track of all of the claims that the app
  requires?  And how do I then make sure that users have all of the
  claims they require and manage this over time?
- How do I prevent an explosion fine grained claims that leads to unwieldy claims management and complex authorization rules?

I'm looking for some guidance or reference implementations of claims authorization that supports fine grained control while also being easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, WIF is used with an IDP like ADFS (which sits on top of AD).

The claims are configured on ADFS not WIF. The claims configured on ADFS are sent to WIF in the SAML token. To find the claims configured for the application you have to look at ADFS.

Claims are not dynamic i.e. if a user attribute is changed in AD, the claim will not be updated until the next time the user logs in.

Trying to limit the numbers of claims configured for a user and ensuring that AD is correctly configured are not trivial issues. One way to do this is via groups (AD security roles). ADFS can map these for you.